# monitors connected via USB-C not showing as connected

Tags: arch-linux, x11, display, displaylink

Running on an arch machine, and I have 2 monitors connected to my laptop via a USB-C hub.

I have to my knowledge installed it according to the arch guide on displaylink, and it was working up until today.

So today I did run `pacman -Syuu` and restarted and everything was working. After that I did unplug the USB hub while the laptop was closed, which seems to have caused some issues as it was unresponsive when I plugged it back in... and I couldn't get the monitors working.

so it shows up as disconnected right now

```
$ xrandr -q | grep connected
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and I can see 3 providers (1 & 2 has been offloaded to 0)

```
~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x10b cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 2: id: 0xe9 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

I've tried reinstalling `evdi-git` and `displaylink` but no luck.

Restarting the displaylink service isn't helping either

and here is the settings to X

```
  - path: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-evdidevice.conf
    content: |-
      Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "DisplayLink"
        MatchDriver "evdi"
        Driver "modesetting"
        Option  "AccelMethod" "none"
      EndSection
  - path: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
    content: |-
      Section "Device"
        Identifier "DisplayLink"
        Driver "modesetting"
        Option "PageFlip" "false"
      EndSection
```

(https://github.com/munHunger/soft-sync-data/blob/master/software/displaylink.yml)

Answer (score 2):

ok, that was 3 hours down the drain.
I had restarted everything unplugged and re plugged everything *except* the power cable to the USB hub.

So a restart of the USB-C hub fixed it